# How to put the candidate's declaration chapter and certificate chapter in the same page and in the center in latex report

Tags: formatting

% Also, how can I reduce the spacing between the front matter in table of contents.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{20pt}



\pagenumbering{roman}


\begin{document}

\chapter*{\underline{CANDIDATE'S DECLARATION}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Candidate's Declaration}%
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\

\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\chapter*{\underline{CERTIFICATE}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Certificate}%
This is to certify that the above statement made by the candidate is correct to best of my knowledge and belief.
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\begin{flushright}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
 Professor\\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
xxxxxxxxxxx
\end{flushright}

\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

and in center

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can redefine `\cleardoublepage` and `\clearpage` to do nothing to get no new page for your second `\chapter*{}`. To get both chapters centered you have to add `\centering` in the `\titleformat` and redefine it after you need not centering any more ...

Please see the following code (dirty hack!):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{showframe}% <============ to visualize typing area and margins

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
%                          ^^^^^^^^^^  <================================
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{20pt}



\pagenumbering{roman}


\begin{document}

\chapter*{\underline{CANDIDATE'S DECLARATION}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Candidate's Declaration}%
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\

\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace{\baselineskip} % <=====

{\let\cleardoublepage\relax % <=====================================
\let\clearpage\relax % <============================================
\chapter*{\underline{CERTIFICATE}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Certificate}%
}

This is to certify that the above statement made by the candidate is correct to best of my knowledge and belief.
\vspace{2cm} % <========================================================
\begin{flushright}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
 Professor\\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
xxxxxxxxxxx
\end{flushright}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display] % <=====================================
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

and the result (please see that you should not use several `\\` to get a vertical space, use `\vspace{2cm}` instead and change the value to your needs):

[image: resulting pdf]

As you can see (package `showframe` shows the typing area in the pdf, delete/comment it for real printing) your first chapter is a little bit too long, `Certificate` is centered, `Contents` is not centered.